# Multiple calls to model_fn

Tags: tensorflow

I'm struggling with understanding what exactly happens during multiple calls to model_fn if you define your own estimator. I've found a discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13895) and the following comment

> The code and doc is correct, it just doesn't emphasize enough that it rebuilds the graph from scratch for each method, and for evaluate/predict is loads variables from the most recent checkpoint.

However I still do not understand:

1. When you call estimator.predict (...) after estimator.train (...), does that mean the current graph (the default one if I understand well) is deleted and replaced with a new one?
2. How is the graph saved after training? Does it refer to variables by their names? If so what happens when we do not provide names (automatic names are given but does this mean we would have to build the different parts of the computational graph in the same order?)

Comment: Noise reduction; layout.